# Teams log files remotely?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I presume this is not possible as need to ask the user to generate the Teams logs.  Im awar eneed to ask the user to press ctrl alr sht 1

or is there a way to do this?

to remote run teams logs and collect from a rmeote pc..

thanks

trying to remote find a solution